# VBScript insertar fecha dentro de ruta

Tags: date, vbscript

Estoy haciendo un proceso en VBScript.
Necesito copiar unos archivos de una carpeta  a otra otra.
Eso ya está hecho, pero el problema es que el nombre de la carpeta desde la que se copia varía cada semana, debido a que corresponde a la fecha. Así es: `Sem_20170228`.

Entonces necesito que dentro del string del nombre, agregar esa variable.
La fecha está formateada para que aparezca así YYYYMMD y se me desordenó el código

Código:

```
Option Explicit


Dim g_oSB : Set g_oSB = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")

Function sprintf(sFmt, aData)
   g_oSB.AppendFormat_4 sFmt, (aData)
   sprintf = g_oSB.ToString()
   g_oSB.Length = 0
End Function


Dim fso
Dim dt : dt = now()


'WScript.Echo sprintf("{0:yyyyMMdd}", Array(dt))
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If 
    filesys.FileExists("C:Bibliotecas\Documentos\Sem_" +dt "\*.pdf")
Then

'filesys.CopyFile "C:Bibliotecas\Documentos\Sem_" +dt "\*.pdf", "C:\Users\alpnheg\Documents\TUTORIALES"
```

Comment: la variable `FECHA` como la estás creando?. Ademas te fatla concatenar los strings y variables con `+`

Comment: re hice la pregunta

Comment: Recuerda editar la pregunta para añdir informacion ,no en los comentarios

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por el interés, ya lo solucioné 
saludos

```
Dim ruta1, ruta2
ruta1 = "C:\Ruta_inicio\Sem_"& Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) &"\*.pdf"
ruta2 = "C:\Ruta_destino"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile (ruta1) , (ruta2)
```